# the space in the middle in a 2 x 2 grid is different from the other spaces?

Tags: css

I am looking for some solution hopefully in `flexbox` to get a result like this image:

[image]

I currently don't know how to make all my `containers` have a `uniform space`.

this image show my problem, the `spaces` in the middle of each `containers` is different to the rest of `spaces`

[image]

How can I fix it and what am I doing wrong?

```css
.container_square {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.container_card {
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 98%;
  width: 98%;
}

.h-100{
 height:100% !important;
}

body,html{
 height:100%;
 width:100%;
 border:1px solid red;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="row no-gutters h-100 overflow-auto">
        <div class="col-6  container_square">
            <div class="container_card">
                1
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6  container_square">
            <div class="container_card">
                2
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6  container_square">
            <div class="container_card">
                3
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6  container_square">
            <div class="container_card">
                4
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to do with flex what's easier to do with grid, any reason you want it to be a flex and not a grid (you even used the `grid` word in the title), you have the `grid-gap` property for grids to set that space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @arieljuod mentioned, CSS Grid is your friend here. It allows for everything to be accomplished with very little css.

I'm also using a css variable to make the margin easily adjustable in one place and keep everything correct.

Here's some [information on css grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

The basics of what is being used in this solution is:

2 rows and 2 columns each with `1fr` size. The meaning of `fr` is a fractional unit. The grid will divide the area of the grid into fractional units after all non fractional units are accounted for (i.e. px, em, rem). The 1 in this is the ratio, so `1fr 1fr` splits the area into halves. `1fr 2fr` would have the first be 1/3, and the second be 2/3. This allows us to use more complicated spaces without having to use weird fractions or percentages. Although it's a bit simplified for that.

`grid-gap: 5px; gap: 5px;` is two ways of saying that the gap between tracks in the grid should be of size `5px`. [`gap`](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/g/gap/) is the newer way that is allows for it to be used in flex-box as well, but unfortunately isn't implemented in Safari as of yet. Which is why I included the older `grid-gap` so it'll work in Safari.

The last thing of interest is [CSS Variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Using_CSS_custom_properties). These allow us to set up variables within pure CSS and perform manipulations using them. You can define them in any selector and they cascade down. The usual place to define them is in `:root{}`, but this is more local than that, so I defined it where it was needed.

You can access a CSS Variable using `var(--variable-name)` which will allow it to be used as a value in most of CSS. You can also specify a default value in case the variable isn't defined yet: `var(--variable-name,10px)`.

Enjoy!

```css
.spaced-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  /* You can change margin to whatever you want it to be */
  --margin: 20px;
  height: calc(100% - ( 2 * var(--margin))) !important;
  width: calc(100% - ( 2 * var(--margin))) !important;
  margin: var(--margin) !important;
  grid-gap: var(--margin);
  gap: var(--margin);
}

.container_card {
  border: 1px solid black;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: none;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="spaced-grid">
  <div class="container_card">
    1
  </div>
  <div class="container_card">
    2
  </div>
  <div class="container_card">
    3
  </div>
  <div class="container_card">
    4
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! I think I should learn about CSS grid, meanwhile, can you please explain to me what is `fr`

Comment: @yavg, I've added a lot of explanation of the CSS that this solution uses and links to further reading.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I found this solution by using just display:flex (so just flexbox) (source https://codepen.io/mogpt/pen/ebXdzg )

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  width: 1000px; /*width can be change*/
}
.grid2x2 {
  min-height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  border: solid 5px red;
  margin: 10px;
}
.grid2x2 > div {
  display: flex; 
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 30px); /*play with - XXpx if problem*/
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.grid2x2 > div > div {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.box1 { background-color: red; 
margin: 20px 10px 10px 20px;}
.box2 { background-color: orange; 
margin: 20px 20px 10px 10px;}
.box3 { background-color: purple; 
margin: 10px 10px 20px 20px;}
.box4 { background-color: grey; 
margin: 10px 20px 20px 10px;}
```

```html
<div class="grid2x2">
  <div class="box box1"><div>one</div></div>
  <div class="box box2"><div>two</div></div>
  <div class="box box3"><div>three</div></div>
  <div class="box box4"><div>four</div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! the first snippet does not have all spaces equal and the second solution varies a bit based on my structure

Comment: Is my EDIT more what you want?

Comment: thanks for your answer, but the space in the middle is not the same as on the other sides

Comment: Indeed, I hadn't noticed it. Normally now it is corrected. Explanation: in .grid2x2 > div, you define the width to be taken minus XX pixels. These pixels are then used to create your margin (on the outsides 20px for example and between 2 divs only 10px because 2 times 10px gives a margin of 20px).